# Google API - order results by distance

Tags: google-geocoding-api

I was wondering the best way to order a set of results by distance using the Google Geocode API, ideally the PHP version. The user will be able to get their current location, I'd then want a set of locations (which I have lat/longs for) to be ordered by distance from their location lat/long.

Comment: Have a look at Places API nearby search: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests

Comment: @xomena I did, but that returns a list of lat/longs from the API....whereas I want to order my own set of lat/longs by distance from the users current location

Answer (score 0):

If you already have all the latlngs, you don't need an API for this: you can easily calculate distances using the [Haversine formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) and sort them.